# How to "read" if let expressions?

Tags: rust, syntax, pattern-matching

In Rust, you can use `if let` instead of `match` when it comes to unwrapping and directly using just a simple value.

So instead of

```rust
match opt_val {
    Some(x) => {
        do_something_with(x);
    }
    _ => {}
}
```

[you can do](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/160)

```
if let Some(x) = opt_val {
    do_something_with(x);
}
```

How should I *read* or *process* this code mentally? For `match`, this is straightforward: "If `opt_val` is *matched* by `Some(x)` then do... with `x`".

For `if let` I always have the impression that it is the wrong way round: "If `Some(x)` matches(?) `opt_val`, then do....". Note that there is no `let` in this sentence.

It is no big deal, but I continue to stumble over this.

---

I really like "*if this let binding succeeds then...*" from the accepted answer, as I think it sets the right focus. Concentrating too much on the pattern matching got me into this "problem" in the first place.
For reference, (ir)refutability and `let` is discussed [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-02-refutability.html) in the Rust book.

Comment: Left hand side is a pattern, right hand side is an object that you match against the pattern. The pattern describes the structure of the object, but instead of describing the whole structure you replace some parts with your own names (identifiers). So you want to match (or may I say tear apart) the object `optVal` and you match name `x` to the inner part of the option, but only in case the option is `Some`

Comment: If your object is say a tuple of 3 options, you match the object like this `let (Some(x), None, _) = obj`, so you say that you tear apart the tuple into 3 parts, from the first you extract the content of `Some` and save it in `x`, for the second you require it to be `None` and the last can be anything

Comment: "if Some(x) matches optval" is not at all bad, actually. You can omit the `let` in reading, but understand them to introduce a variable binding, as usual.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better... I find this extremely confusing as well

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You shouldn't expect the keywords in the syntax of any programming language to map directly to words in English, or any other natural language.

`let` expressions in Rust always accept a pattern, which lets you do things like:

```
let foo = (1, (2, 3));
let (a, (b, _)) = foo;
```

However, this only works when the pattern is *irrefutable*, that is it will always match.

`if let` extends this to accommodate types that may not always match.

How you are reading it is just fine: "if the pattern matches then...", or "if this let binding succeeds then...".

Comment: Languages should map their keywords to English, within reason, if they want to be somewhat popular (cf Perl, APL...). I think `let` maps pretty well there.