# Rust Lang: What is "if let Some(x) = x" doing?

Tags: rust

I'm working on a rust project written a couple of years ago, and have come across this piece of code, which is literally:

```rust
let mut values = vec![];
for x in maybe_values {
    if let Some(x) = x {
        values.push(Arc::new(x));
    }
}
```

I understand that "if let" introduces a pattern-matching if (Which seems to be a poor re-use of the keyword "let", but I will get over that - If anyone can help me with a mental mnemonic to make sense of "let" here, please do!).

But what is the test `Some(x) = x` doing?

From my testing, it seems to be a trick/idiom to both a) test that the loop variant 'x' is Some(), and also b) end up with the unwrap()ped value in x.

But I can't fully explain it to myself, and can't find reference to this being an idiom anywhere.

Hope you can help my Rust education path. Thanks.

Comment: [How to "read" if let expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65684540/7884305); [Why is the let keyword in if-let?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66516075/7884305)

Comment: The `x` in `Some(x)` is a brand new variable, so I think the `let` is warranted. If anything, `let` is missing from pattern matching in a match statement: `match opt { Some(x) => {}, None => {} }` creates a variable `x` without a `let`, and this can be confusing if `x` is also the name of a `const` in scope.

Comment: @BallpointBen Actually, by logic it should be `if Some(let x) = ...`, same in let statements and maybe even parameter declarations. And I know some people regret not having a variable matching modifier (like `let`) in patterns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two completely different variables in play here. It's equivalent to.

```
let mut values = vec![];
for x_1 in maybe_values {
  if let Some(x_2) = x_1 {
    values.push(Arc::new(x_2));
  }
}
```

In Rust, the right-hand side of a `let` is evaluated with the left-hand variable *not* in scope, so when the `if let` is evaluated, the outer `x` is still in-scope. Then, if it's a `Some` value, we make a *new* variable `x` which contains the inside of the `Option`. This variable [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the previous `x`, making it inaccessible inside the `if` statement (in the same way that a function argument called `x` would render a global variable named `x` inaccessible by shadowing).

Comment: Thanks! Not sure who replied first, but will give you the win for leading with the core answer - They are 2 separate variables, but both called x!

Answer (score 24):

This is a shorthand for using a full match statement when you only care about matching a single use case.

So this block of code:

```rust
if let x = y {
   foo();
} else {
   bar();
}
```

Is equivalent to using a full match:

```rust
match y {
    x => {
        foo();
    }
    _ => {
        bar();
    }
}
```

For your specific case, it is equivalent to this. The inner x uses the same name as the outer variable which can be confusing, but they are two separate values.

```rust
let mut values = vec![];
for x in maybe_values {
    match x {
        Some(y) => values.push(Arc::new(y)),
        _ => {},
    }
}
```

Comment: If I could grant two green ticks I would   ;-)   I never thought of "if let" creating that new inner variable on the left hand side. That helps to make the use of "let" a bit clearer! TBH, when I started reading Rust code the "if let" statements were some of the strangest to me... Thanks. Personally I would try to avoid using the same variable name - "There is no team prize for tricky code!" Quite the contrary...

Answer (score 2):

My 2 cents: Another good mnemonic to understand/remember `if-let` is as a shortcut to a very common pattern: `if a.is_some() { let b = a.unwrap() ... }` :

Full pattern:

```
let mut values = vec![];
for x_1 in maybe_values {
    if x_1.is_some() {
       let x_2 = x_1.unwrap()
       values.push(Arc::new(x_2));
    }
}
```

the shortcut `if-let` means joining the `if x_1.is_some()` and the `let x_2 = x.unwrap()` in a single `if-let` statement

With the shortcut:

```
let mut values = vec![];
for x_1 in maybe_values {
    if let Some(x_2) = x_1 {
       values.push(Arc::new(x_2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `maybe_values` is full of `Options`. Some are `None` and some values are `Some(x)`

if the `maybe_value` is not a None (meaning it is able to match `Some(x)`), it will be appended to the `values` vec.

This for loop essentially cleans out the `None`/`NULL` values of the `maybe_values` vec into a vec (`for_sure_are_values`) where all the values DO exist.